# 415 Unsupported Media Type Using JQuery/FormData and Web Api

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting a Error :

```
"POST {URL} 415 (Unsupported Media Type)" error
```

And cannot figure out why it's happening.

I'm trying to upload an excel file in **`JQuery using FormData.`**

Here is the **code:**

```
var formdata = new FormData();
var file = input.get(0).files[0];
formdata.append('content', file);

var url = "/Phrase/Import/" + $('.exportPanel #Language').val()

var ajax = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //Do something.
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Do something.
    }
});
```

Here is the controller code:

```
[Route("Import/{languageID}")]
[HttpPost]
public void ImportPhrases([FromUri]int languageID, [FromBody]Stream content)
{
    _service.ImportPhrases(content, languageID);          
}
```

I noticed that, according to Fiddler, the content type of the request is different to that of the response (not sure if this makes a difference?).

```
Request: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Response: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The JQuery above is being used in a different part of the system, but uses WCF instead of Web API (am in the process of changing from WCF to MVC/Web API), again I'm not sure if this makes a difference?

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **415 Unsupported Media Type**
>
> The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support. For example, the client uploads an image as image/svg+xml, but the server requires that images use a different format.

`contentType` does matter - it tells the server what you are uploading.  In this instance, you have set the value to `false`.  The server cannot recognise this, so it returns false.  If you do not need a specific content type, you should remove the `contentType` line to allow the jQuery default to kick in.

Comment: Many thanks, that certainly answered the question! I'm just getting an Internal Server Error 500, something to do with the file within the formdata being null- but that's a different issue.